# Is it always true that $\int_{\Omega_n} f h\ dx = 0$ for any $h \in C_c (\Omega_n)$ eventually?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Definition (Local Integrability)** $:$ Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ be an open subset and $f : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a real valued function defined on $\Omega.$ Then $f$ is said to be locally integrable on $\Omega$ if for any compact subset $K \subseteq \Omega$ we have $f \in L^1 (K).$ The set of all locally integrable functions on $\Omega$ is denoted by $L^1_{\text {loc}} (\Omega).$

> **Proposition** $:$ Let $f \in L^1_{\text {loc}} (\Omega)$ be such that $$\int_{\Omega} f g\ dx = 0$$ for all $g \in C_c (\Omega).$ Then $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega.$

The proof of this theorem is divided into parts.

The author* first proved the proposition for integrable function $f$ defined on $\Omega$ by using the density of $C_c (\Omega)$ in $L^1 (\Omega),$ where the Lebesgue measure $|\Omega|$ of $\Omega$ is taken to be finite. I have no issue with this part.

In the next step he proved the proposition for any locally integrable function $f$ on $\Omega$ for any open subset $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^N.$ For that he restricted $f$ to $\Omega_n$ where $\Omega_n = \Omega \cap B (0, n).$ Now since $\overline {\Omega_n}$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$ and $f$ is locally integrable on $\Omega$ it follows that $f \in L^1 \left (\overline {\Omega_n} \right )$ and hence $f \in L^1 (\Omega_n).$ Now he said that since $\left |\Omega_n \right | \lt +\infty$ we can use the first part to conclude that $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega_n$ for all $n \geq 1$ and since $\Omega = \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \Omega_n$ it follows that $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega,$ as countable union of sets of measure zero is again a set of measure zero. This completes the proof.

For the second part how did the author know that $\int_{\Omega_n} f h\ dx = 0$ for all $h \in C_c (\Omega_n)$ eventually after a certain stage by the given condition? This is where I got stuck and couldn't able to understand the reason behind it. Could anyone please make it clear to me?

Thanks a bunch.

---

***Source** $:$ *Functional Analysis* by S. Kesavan (**Proposition 6.3.3,** Page no. $173$).

Comment: @BrianMoehring$:$ Good point. But does that modification help anyway?

Comment: With your question?  No.  With making the proof valid?  Yes.

Comment: @Brian Moehring$:$ That doesn't make the step $2$ of the proof valid entirely but to some extent. My question still remains.

Comment: @Brian Moehring$:$ Also I think you need to substract closed balls in order to make $\Omega_n$ open so that they meet the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my accounting, the proof has only one error, right here:

> Now since $\overline {\Omega_n}$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$ and $f$ is locally integrable on $\Omega$ it follows that $f \in L^1 \left (\overline {\Omega_n} \right )$ and hence $f \in L^1 (\Omega_n).$

As defined, $\overline {\Omega_n}$, while compact, may not be a subset of $\Omega$, so we would only be able to conclude $f \in L^1_\text{loc}(\Omega_n)$, which isn't sufficient for the rest of the proof.

The simplest fix I can see is to write instead
$$\Omega_n = \Omega \cap B(0,n) \setminus \overline{\bigcup_{x \not\in \Omega} B(x,\tfrac1n)}$$

From here, we can conclude $f \in L^1(\overline{\Omega_n})$ for the same reasoning given in the original argument, but now there is something to show in order to conclude $\Omega = \bigcup_n \Omega_n$.

---

As for your question, I don't actually see your issue.  Let's run through the details a little more closely in the proof.

We are assuming that $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and that $\int_{\Omega} fg\,\rm{d}x = 0$ for every $g \in C_c(\Omega)$.

With the above fix, $f|_{\Omega_n} \in L^1(\Omega_n)$ and $$\int_{\Omega_n}f|_{\Omega_n}g\,\rm{d}x = \int_\Omega fg\,\rm{d}x = 0$$
for every $g \in C_c(\Omega_n) \subseteq C_c(\Omega)$.  By the first part, $f|_{\Omega_n} = 0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega_n$.

Now use the fact, as mentioned, that $\Omega = \bigcup_n \Omega_n$ and the countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero.

Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Wait! Wait! Wait! How do you have $\int_{\Omega_n} f \big \rvert_{\Omega_n} g\ dx = \int_{\Omega} fg\ dx\ $? How do you even know that $C_c (\Omega_n) \subseteq C_c (\Omega)\ $? We are supposed to use the first part and the hypothesis that $$\int_{\Omega} fg\ dx = 0$$ for any $g \in C_c (\Omega).$

Comment: @Anacardium You should be able to show both those facts.  Like I said, I just cleared up the details.  Show that $A \subset B$ implies $C_c(A) \subset C_c(B)$ and note that if an equation is true for every $g$ in a set, then it's true for every $g$ in a smaller set.  That's it.

Comment: Woah. Why does this have three downvotes?

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more like how $C_c (A) \subseteq C_c (B).$ Can every continuous function be extended from $A$ to $B$ with support being unaltered? Looks like I am not familiar with those stuffs.

Comment: @Anacardium If a function has compact support which is a subset of $A$, and $A$ is a subset of $B$, then the function has compact support, which is a subset of $B$.

Comment: Second condition of fixing doesn't make much of sense to me because I am supposed to use the first part where $f$ is assumed to be integrable.

Comment: But how to extend it from $A$ to $B\ $? We are supposed to get a function on $B$ first of all.

Comment: The second way to fix it depends on how the author proved the first part, which I cannot see.

Comment: @BrianMoehring$:$ You can have a look at this proof. I have mentioned the proposition number along with the page number.

Comment: Why is the "error" an error? If $f\in L^1(\overline{\Omega_n})$ it is surely in $L^1(\Omega_n)$

Comment: @Fshrike$:$ We can't always say that $\overline {\Omega_n} \subseteq \Omega$ if $\Omega_n = \Omega \cap B (0, n).$ That's why he did some modification.

Comment: Now I get your point. We extend any $g \in C_c (\Omega_n)$ by zero on $\Omega \setminus \Omega_n$ and then everything fits nicely. Many many thanks for your remark.

Comment: @Anacardium I did not recognise what the error was supposed to be. Now I see, they were objecting to "compact *subset*"

Comment: @FShrike$:$ Hmm. But I don't understand why is the downvote. It's a perfectly valid answer to my question.

Comment: @Anacardium I didn't downvote! I am equally surprised at the number of downvotes